# How can I use show component inside a ListItemText?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I used the `ListItemText` to display the list and my goal is to use the show component in the `react-admin` when each row of the list is clicked, but the function related to the display is not executed? How should it be done?

Contacts.js

```
/// --- List ---
export const ContactList = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <List className={classes.list} {...props} pagination={false} exporter={false} filters={<ContactFilter/>}>
      <ContactSimpleList/>
    </List>
  )
};

/// --- Child list ---
const ContactSimpleList = () => {
  const {ids, data} = useListContext();

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    ShowContact(id);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {ids.map(id => (
        <ListItem key={id} button>
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt="Profile Picture" src={data[id].person}/>
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText primary={data[id].name} onClick={() => handleClick(id)}/>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

/// --- Show ---
export const ShowContact = (props) => (
  <Show {...props} actions={<ShowActionsOnTopToolbar/>} title={<ContactTitle/>}>
    <SimpleShowLayout>
      <TextField source="id"/>
      <TextField source="name"/>
      <TextField source="numbers.number" label="Number"/>
      <TextField source="numbers.type" label="Type Call"/>
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
```

Comment: I understood what was right for this case: use the react-router-dom, `<ListItem key={id} button onClick={() => history.push(`/contacts/${id}/show`)} >`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do; replace Typography with your component

```
<ListItemText
  disableTypography
  primary={
    <Typography>Pedroview</Typography>
  }
/>
```